# Do system apps automatically get root permissions?

Tags: adb, root-access, system-apps

If I install the famous App "Tincore Key Mapper" as a system app, will it get the required root permissions without my phone being rooted or damaged? If the answer is positive: How to do that via ADB?

Answer (score 3):

If your phone isn't rooted, then **none** of the apps can get root access, regardless of whether they are installed as system app. Also, I quite doubt how you can install extra system apps without root. Rooting may require a custom recovery and may not be easily done with only ADB.

Comment: Exactly that (+1). But, if installed as system app, it can use permissions restricted to such (i.e. permission-levels 'system' and 'systemOrSignature') if requested. Moreover, an app doesn't get permissions automatically, it must explicitly request them via its `Manifest`. Same for apps that should use "root powers": no app runs with "root powers" automatically without explicitly requesting root access itself.

Comment: @Izzy Some apps use exploits to acquire and even "conquer" root permissions. For example [KingRoot steals root from SuperSU](/q/171686).

Comment: I could say "now you contradict yourself" – as your answer text states the opposite. But yes, using exploits (if available) a malicious app could do that. And some in fact do, then migrating themselves to system apps (to survive even a factory-reset). As far as I've heard, some even root the device without the knowledge of the user. But IMHO the question wasn't about that aspect ;)

Answer (score 0):

The system apps do not have root access, but they have a lot of access. Maybe you can install Magisk Manager like a system app and gain "something like root". Installing system apps can't be done by adb, unless the phone is already rooted.

Theoretically, you intercept the phone's WiFi traffic (Bettercap) while it is updating a normal system app like Camera (update from the Settings.) Then you can modify the `camera.apk` file of the fly and put the `magisk.apk`.

This won't work on every device because most of the phones check if the app is signed by the manufacturer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).